# How to pass arguments to the event listener's function so that there would be no duplicate event listeners?

Tags: javascript

Currently, I use the following solution:

```
<button onclick="initiate('ok2')" id="btn1">Initiate</button>
<button id="btn2">Send data</button>
```

```
function initiate(ok) {
   document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", receiveData);
}

function receiveData(event) {
   console.log(event);
}
```

The benefit of this approach lies in the named function receiveData, which is recognized as the same function and is not added repeatedly.

Steps to reproduce:

- Press the 'Initiate' button multiple times
- Press 'Send data'

Result: console log is printed only once

I want to utilize the same approach, but add an attribute to the function. I tried the bind approach, but the event listener is added multiple times. As a result, the console log is also printed multiple times.

Example:

```
function initiate(ok) {
  document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", receiveData.bind(null, ok));
}

function receiveData(event, ok) {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(ok);
}
```

Is it possible to pass an argument to a function and not create duplicate event listeners? Ideally, it would be preferred not to delete event listeners, like in the current solution.

Comment: Whats the point of add event listener if you are using on click?

Comment: during page initialization, add the event listeneer to btn2 then. instead of on button press? I dont see why you would want to add the listener more than once

Comment: Why do you need to bind a click in a click? Best solution is to not need to do it.

Comment: It is a simplified example. In the problem I am solving, there is communication between iFrame and the parent window using an event listener (window.addEventListener("message", handler))

Comment: Simply use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/215552). rather than binding a new event handler on every click.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version with the recommended ways of delegating and setting and getting data attribute

A user cannot click what is not visible so no need to initiate the button, just unhide it

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let btn = e.target
  if (btn.matches("#btn1")) {
    let targetBTN = document.getElementById(btn.dataset.target);
    targetBTN.hidden = false;
  } else if (btn.matches("#btn2")) {
    console.log(btn.dataset.field);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1" data-target="btn2">Initiate</button>
<button id="btn2" data-field="ok2" hidden>Send data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// when the window loads add a click handler to the button of choice
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is now loaded');
  document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", receiveData)
});

function receiveData(event) {
  console.log(event);
}
```

or as suggested in comments, add the click handler inline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tel it if it is inited or not..

```js
    let data = "";
        let init = true;
        function initiate(ok) {
          
           data = ok
           if(init ){
             document.getElementById("btn2")
             .addEventListener("click", receiveData);
             init = false
            }
        }
        
        function receiveData(event) {
           console.log( data );
        }
```

```html
<button onclick="initiate('ok2')" id="btn1">Initiate</button>
<button id="btn2">Send data</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the one goal is to only allow the second button to be able to be used when the first button is clicked.

So, I attached an event listener to the document. Then used data attributes on the buttons to determine if the start button can be used or not. And just for display I used CSS to hide the start button if its not allowed to be used just yet

```js
document.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  let btn = e.target
  if(btn.matches(".btn-start")){
    let targetBTN = document.querySelector(`[data-id='${btn.dataset.target}']`)
    targetBTN.setAttribute("data-initiated","true");
  }
  else if(btn.dataset.initiated == "true"){
    console.log(btn.dataset.field);
  }
});
```

```css
[data-initiated="false"]{
 display:none
}

[data-initiated="true"]{
 display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<button data-target="send2" class="btn-start">Initiate</button>
<button data-initiated="false" data-field="ok2" data-id="send2" class="btn-send">Send data</button>
```

Comment: Please: `if(btn.matches(".btn-start")){` or `if(btn.classList.contains("btn-start")){` !!!

Comment: @mplungjan, thank you. I took your first suggestion, just fixed the spelling.

Comment: `if(btn.dataset.initiated == "true"){  console.log(btn.dataset.field);`

Comment: @mplungjan, what's the advantage of dataset over getAttribute?

Comment: Readability: `document.querySelector(\`[data-id='${btn.dataset.target}']\`)`

Comment: ditto `targetBTN.dataset.initiated="true"`